# flask_sqlalchemy: ImportError: cannot import name db

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I can't resolve this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name db

with the error trace:

> File "../celery-scheduler/app/models.py", line 3, in 
>       from app import db

Package versions installed:

```
celery==4.1.1
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
SQLAlchemy==1.2.10
```

Here is the structure of the folders:

```
celery-scheduler
  app
    tasks
      __init__.py
      test.py
    templates
      races.html
    __init__.py
    models.py
```

I guess the many ways to initialize and use a database is confusing me. How it works: Celery worker will fetch data from an API on a periodic basis, then store it in a database and the results will be rendered.

**celery-scheduler/config.py**

```
from os import environ
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

REDIS_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
REDIS_PORT = 6379
BROKER_URL = environ.get('REDIS_URL', "redis://{host}:{port}/0".format(
    host=REDIS_HOST, port=str(REDIS_PORT)))
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = BROKER_URL
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from celery import Celery
import celeryconfig

f1 = Flask(__name__)
f1.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(f1)

def make_celery(app):
    # create context tasks in celery
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        broker=app.config['BROKER_URL']
    )
    celery.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask

    return celery

celery = make_celery(f1)

@f1.route('/data/races/all', methods=['GET'])
def race():
    races_from_db = Race.query().all()
    return render_template('races.html', races_from_db=races_from_db)
```

**app/models.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import db

class Race(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'races'
    raceId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

    def __init__(self):
        self.raceId = raceId
        self.url = url
```

**app/tasks/test.py**

```
import celery
from celery.task.base import periodic_task
from app.models import Race
from app import db

@periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(seconds=300), bind=True)
def periodic_run_get_manifest():
    ...generates dataframe of data...
    races = df_races.to_json(orient='records')
    r = Race(races)
    db.session.add(r)
    db.session.commit()
```